# Mapbox JS: Efficient and simple way to change a property of a feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, algorithm, mapbox

I am trying to change the property (`value`) of a feature (based upon `id`) in a layer. I **cannot use** `setFeatureState`, because I need to cluster the features based on the `value` property and `clusterProperties` does not support feature-state aggregation. The current way I'm using to set the `value` property of a feature with a specific `id` is the following (every 2 seconds, I iterate through **every** feature in the GeoJSON and set the property):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const newGeojson = {
    ...geojson,
    features: geojson.features.map(feature => {
      if ([0, 1].includes(feature.id)) { // update features selectively
        feature.properties.value= 1;
      }
      return feature;
    })
  };
  map.getSource('geom').setData(newGeojson);
}, 2000);
```

This is terribly inefficient with a time complexity of O(nk), with k being the number of features I want to change—I have around **130,000 features**. In fact, it causes my browser to crash. I tried using mapbox-gl-js's MapboxDraw (mapbox-gl-js has a `setFeatureProperty`method), but it takes too long to load the 130,000 features (crashing the browser), so that didn't work as an option. Is there a more feasible option where I can set the property of a feature **at runtime** without it taking forever?

My GeoJSON (`geojson` variable) is of the following format (Mapbox **requires GeoJSON data**):

```
{ 
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[ 
        { 
            "type":"Feature",
            "id":0,
            "geometry":{ 
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[ 
                    1.49129,
                    42.46372
                ]
            },
            "properties":{ 
                "country":"AD",
                "city":"Sant Julià de Lòria-0",
                "value":0
            }
        },
        { 
            "type":"Feature",
            "id":1,
            "geometry":{ 
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[ 
                    1.73361,
                    42.54277
                ]
            },
            "properties":{ 
                "country":"AD",
                "city":"Pas de la Casa-1",
                "value":0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the expected number of features?

Comment: @ManishRaj Around 130,000 features.

Comment: How often do they get updated and what's the nature of these updates? Real-time data, user interaction, data coming from API calls or websocket?

Comment: @ManishRaj They get updated everytime a user connects to the site (user interaction).

Comment: If the updates are one-time only i.e. when user connects, then you should be doing that processing on server or even clients since browsers can loop through 130k items fairly quickly.

Comment: @ManishRaj Got it. I also forgot to mention that the features need to be updated everytime a user moves to a new location on the map. I'm using Node.js, so I don't want to do computationally intensive tasks server-side—I'm updating the features client-side. It should still be fairly quick right?

Comment: Yep that'd work if you're using `moveend` instead of `move`.

Comment: sorry if the question is stupid, but is `[0, 1]` just an example?

Comment: @WalterTross Yes, [0, 1] is just an example.

Comment: it's not clear how your iteration goes. If on every iteration you have a different value where in your example you have `[0, 1]`, it looks like what you are doing is O(n²)

Comment: @WalterTross I believe my current method is O(nk), where k is the number of features that I want to change. I go through every feature in the GeoJSON (O(n)), and then for each feature, I check if it's id (feature.id) is a feature I want to change O(k).

Comment: 130,000 seems really excessive. Why not separate these into different datasets and/or layers? I doubt there's an efficient alternative for managing that in realtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like what you need is direct access to features, instead of `map`ping all features to just change a few. Something like an ancillary JavaScript object that, given the feature `id` as key, lets you access the feature in order to change its `value`:

```javascript
featureById = {}
geojson.features.forEach(f => featureById[f.id] = f) // only once
```

which then allows you to do this (equivalent to your example code):

```javascript
featureById[0].properties.value = 1
featureById[1].properties.value = 1
```

Your original code builds a new array of features for every change. Of course, it's an array of pointers, but it's still a big array. This way you only build `featureById` once. Every change is O(k).

Comment: The problem here is that MapBox needs GeoJSON data as an input. So even though featureById would have the correct data, I would still need to convert it into valid GeoJSON so MapBox can properly display the data.

Comment: no, you don't need to convert it, you can reuse the same modified data, I'm pretty sure. The point is that JavaScript uses pointers (pun intended)

Comment: `featureById` is your fast access into `geojson`, it doesn't hold any copy of a feature, it only has copies of the `id`s and pointers to the features.

Comment: what I don't know is how to optimize further, because I have never had the pleasure to meet mapbox before :-D  But it seems strange to me that you need to do a `setData` of the __whole__ set of features over and over. This could be the real problem you are having.

Comment: great! I'm glad I've been able to help without knowing mapbox :-)